# How to query both SMS and Contacts with same URI?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursorloader

I am working on SMS Module.

I need to give searching contact via name, number and SMS via body?

I am able to search SMS body with CursorLoader via

> content://mms-sms/search

Contacts separately via

> ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI

So is there any separate URI search these two things which i am not aware of or Merge these two under one list With using CursorLoader.

Appreciate any lead.

or is there some way to improve sms search and customize it.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there any separate URI search these two things which i am not aware of or Merge these two under one list

No.

Also, bear in mind that not every SMS will be to or from a user's contact.

Comment: do you have any idea about how apps provide search from Messages

Comment: @RamanSidhu: I would imagine that they query the `Sms` content provider. `content://mms-sms/search` is undocumented and may not exist on all versions of Android, let alone all devices. Try [`SEARCH_URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.MmsSms.html#SEARCH_URI).

Comment: But it only searches from body of message